# Scapy sniff() "an operation was performed on something that is not a socket"

Tags: python, sockets, scapy

I recently installed scapy and was trying to start using it and I'm having trouble using the sniff() function.

I've been able to install Scapy using the steps described in their docs. I'm running Windows 7 x64 and using Python 2.6. I'm able to use the `send` family of functions fine (confirmed with Wireshark) but `sniff()` is failing with the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sniffingStuff.py", line 11, in <module>
    sniff(filter="ip",prn=customAction)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 575, in sniff
    sel = select([s],[],[],remain)
select.error: (10038, 'An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket')
```

The only thing off the top of my head that I thought might be wrong is that I had PCAP installed already because I had Wireshark installed. I looked around and didn't see any useful answers.

Edit: Since I didn't make this clear in my original post, any calls to the sniff function fails, regardless of parameters, filters, etc. For a concrete reference see [here](http://thepacketgeek.com/scapy-sniffing-with-custom-actions-part-1/).

Thanks

Comment: I'm not too familiar with scapy, but it might help others if you add some of your code from `sniffingStuff.py` to the question as well.

Comment: The parameters to the sniff() function in scapy are irrelevant (it fails every time), but I've updated my post above.

Comment: Does it fail even when supplying the interface via the keyword argument `iface`? If it doesn't, what is the current value of `conf.iface`?

Comment: It fails when passing in iface as well; I can send packets on the interface but sniff() fails.

Comment: What is the value of `s` in the failing line? Insert a `pdb` there and try to find out what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that scapy requires a specific version of WinPCAP as per the instructions for installation.  Check the Windows installation guide [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#Windows) for supported version information.

Comment: I've updated my original post- the parameters to sniff() don't matter; they all fail. I'm going to try to set it up with an older version; the version they listed won't install because a newer driver is on the system and I assumed WinPcap wouldn't break compatibility like that.