# python2.7 + windows 7 + scapy: select.error: (10038, '')

Tags: scapy, packet-sniffers

I want to create a sniffer script for monitoring windows and linux. For linux, it is easy, but for windows it is not. I met an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_scapy.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "test_scapy.py", line 38, in main
    sniff(filter="tcp port 80", prn=packet_callback, count=10)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 575, in sniff
    sel = select([s],[],[],remain)
select.error: (10038, '')
```

My code is

```
from scapy.all import *

def packet_callback(packet):
    print packet.show()

sniff(filter="tcp port 80", prn=packet_callback, count=10)
```

I have read the post [Scapy sniff() "an operation was performed on something that is not a socket"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014568/scapy-sniff-an-operation-was-performed-on-something-that-is-not-a-socket)

and read the select document https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html
"File objects on Windows are not acceptable, but sockets are. On Windows, the underlying select() function is provided by the WinSock library, and does not handle file descriptors that don’t originate from WinSock."

I think that means I have to re-define the socket for sniffing. So I upgrade the code

```
# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
    s.bind((HOST, 0))

    # Include IP headers
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

    # receive all packages
    s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

    sniff(filter="tcp port 80", prn=packet_callback, count=10, opened_socket=s)
    s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

That is ok now and the error disappear. But I have to parse the TCP RAW data manually.

> Now the question is: is there any easy way for me to sniffer for
>   windows platform like using linux scapy layer wrapper, like call package[TCP].dst

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: If you have raw traffic bytes you can use corresponding layer to parse it. E.g. `p = Ether(b'...')` would parse the bytes using Ethernet.

Comment: Also, I have updated Windows implementation, but it works out of the box on python3 and Windows 8 and above (without dnet requirement). You can see it here http://github.com/phaethon/scapy

Comment: I am trying to learn cython and pyrex and make it clear for myself later.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Scapy are you using? You should probably update to the latest (2.3.3) version or event better, to the current development version from [GitHub](https://github.com/secdev/scapy).